# Check and save data to update

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a question, I need, at the same time that I check, I need to save the value of a query to perform an update. How is it possible to do this? Someone help me?

```
update table_one tone
set    tone.name = (name)
where  (select tthree.name as name
        from   table_two ttwo
        where  ttwo.name='sfsdf'
        union
        select tthree.name as name
        from   table_three tthree
        where  tthree.name='sfsdf') is not null;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you meant by saying that you want to "save" value of a query (save how? Where?) at the same time that you "check" (how? Where?). True, you posted some code which suggests that `tone.name` should get value of `(name)`, but - what exactly is that `(name)`?

Anyway, this is what I *think* you might need, so - have a look & give it a try.

```
update table_one t1 set
  t1.name = (select max(x.name)
             from (select t2.name from table_two t2 where t2.name = 'sfsdf'
                   union
                   select t3.name from table_three t3 where t3.name = 'sfsdf'
                  ) x
            )
  where exists (select null 
                from (select t2.name from table_two t2 where t2.name = 'sfsdf'
                      union
                      select t3.name from table_three t3 where t3.name = 'sfsdf'
                     )
               );
```

If that's not "it", please, edit the question and post some sample data that illustrate the problem and explain which result you expect and why.